# Custom Logging Module not working in Python

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I want to use same logging mechanism in all python scripts. Developed a class below class:

File Name: ms_logging.py

```
import logging

class ms_logging:
        @staticmethod
        def logging():
            logging.basicConfig(
                level=logging.DEBUG,
                format='%(asctime)s | %(levelname)s | [%(filename)s:%(lineno)d] | %(message)s',
                datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
                filename="/home/etl_developer/ms_de/log_directory/master_log_file.log"
                )
            logger = logging.getLogger()
            return logger
```

Then I'm trying to load that module in another Python script and use that `logging` function to insert logs.
The purpose of this is to write one configuration and use them in all Python scripts to have a centralized logs

Here is the code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/etl_developer/ms_de/module_library/')
from ms_logging import ms_logging

log = ms_logging.logging()
log.error('test')
log.info('hello there')
```

This above code doesn't give any error but logging is also not working. The log file is empty.

What is the mistake that I'm making? Any clues would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You should only call basicConfig once, and you should leave it to the calling program (ie. not a library - at least not automagically). I would suggest reading the Python logging docs and using logging directly. It does everything you want to do...

Comment: Does it work if you have the class in the same file? (Can you verify that what gets imported, is what you expect to be?) Does it work if you use an ordinary function instead of a `@staticmethod` of a class? What exactly appears to be *causing* the problem?

Comment: hi @KarlKnechtel Yes logging works if i use it in the same script. But its not working when I'm importing it to another script file. `@staticmethod` is not a issue here. static method has been used to call the function without creating an object of that class.

Comment: Why do you need a class, or a method/function, at all?

Comment: Hi @thebjorn as mentioned I wanted to use the same configuration in every python script without writing it again and again. My wish is to just import the module and start logging. To import the custom module, I think i do need to define a class and a method to use it. Is there any problem with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply do (ms_logging.py):

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format='%(asctime)s | %(levelname)s | [%(filename)s:%(lineno)d] | %(message)s',
    datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
    filename="/home/etl_developer/ms_de/log_directory/master_log_file.log"
)
log = logging.getLogger()
```

and use it:

```
from ms_logging import log

log.error('test')
log.info('hello there')
```

it seems easier than setting up the entire logging machinery for each logging statement..?

Comment: hi @thebjorn Thank you so much. Its working perfectly. Wondering why my approach didn't work though.

Comment: I don't know, but my initial hypothesis would be that the repeated call to basicConfig is overwriting the file (it's only a guess though) ;-)